# Cant move left or right after i land from jumping

Tags: c#, xna

My problem is after a jump either I land on a platform or the floor and I am unable to move left or right.  I am however able to still jump.

Here is the code i have used:

```
 public void handleInput(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            this.Transform.MoveIncrement = Vector2.Zero;
            float timeBetweenUpdates = 0.25f * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            bPause = true;
            if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(left))
            {
                bPause = false;
                if(playerID == 1)
                {
                this.Presentation.SpriteEffects = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
                }
                else if(playerID == 2)
                {
                    this.Presentation.SpriteEffects = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
                }
                this.Transform.MoveIncrement += -this.Transform.Look * timeBetweenUpdates;
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
            }
            if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(right))
            {
                bPause = false;
                if (playerID == 1)
                {
                    this.Presentation.SpriteEffects = SpriteEffects.None;
                }
                else if(playerID == 2)
                {
                    this.Presentation.SpriteEffects = SpriteEffects.None;
                }
                this.Transform.MoveIncrement += this.Transform.Look * timeBetweenUpdates;
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
            }
            if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(up) && hasJumped == false)
            {
                this.Transform.moveBy(-Vector2.UnitY * 400);
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
                hasJumped = true;
                game.SoundManager.getEffectInstance("JumpSound").Play();
            }
            if (hasJumped == true)
            {
                this.Transform.moveBy(Vector2.UnitY * timeBetweenUpdates);
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
            }
        }
```

This is my players update(How i get my player to move.

```
 PlayerSprite pSprite = (PlayerSprite)collider;
            if((collidee is FloorSprite) && (collider is PlayerSprite ))
            {
                pSprite.hasJumped = false;
            }
            if ((collidee is WallSprite) && (collider is PlayerSprite))
            {
                WallSprite wallSprite = (WallSprite)collidee;
                PlayerSprite playerSprite = (PlayerSprite)collider;

            }
            if ((collidee is PlatformSprite) && (collider is PlayerSprite))
            {
                pSprite.hasJumped = false;
            }
```

This is how I tell if the player has jumped and has landed on something.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(left))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test");
                bPause = false;
                if(playerID == 1)
                {
                this.Presentation.SpriteEffects = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
                }
                else if(playerID == 2)
                {
                    this.Presentation.SpriteEffects = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
                }
                this.Transform.MoveIncrement += -this.Transform.Look * timeBetweenUpdates;
                Console.WriteLine((-this.Transform.Look * timeBetweenUpdates));
                this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
            }
```

Try this, and tell me if you can see 'test' and what is the value of '-this.Transform.Look * timeBetweenUpdates;'

Comment: Yep test is showing up even the animation is playing but its like theres a collidable wall in front of him.

Comment: also time between updates   float timeBetweenUpdates = 0.25f * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

Comment: yeah can you invite me into chat please?